# shakespeare-js fails to compile on Heroku

Tags: haskell, deployment, heroku, web-deployment, yesod

When deploying my simple Yesod application to Heroku cabal fails when installing shakespeare-js-1.0.2

```
Building shakespeare-js-1.0.2...
Building persistent-1.0.2.2...
Building yaml-0.8.2.1...
Building tls-extra-0.6.1...
Failed to install shakespeare-js-1.0.2
Last 10 lines of the build log ( /app//.cabal/logs/shakespeare-js-1.0.2.log ):
Building shakespeare-js-1.0.2...
Preprocessing library shakespeare-js-1.0.2...
[1 of 3] Compiling Text.Julius ( Text/Julius.hs, dist/build/Text/Julius.o )
[2 of 3] Compiling Text.Coffee ( Text/Coffee.hs, dist/build/Text/Coffee.o )
Text/Coffee.hs:56:7:
`preEscapeBegin' is not a (visible) field of constructor `PreConvert'
Text/Coffee.hs:57:7:
`preEscapeEnd' is not a (visible) field of constructor `PreConvert'
```

The project is a simple website that uses WAI and Warp to print a hello world. 
In my cabal file I only specify the latest version of yesod (1.1.9) to see if it was available on Heroku (It doesn't use Yesod or shakespeare-js yet):

```
executable Website
  extensions:NoImplicitPrelude
             TemplateHaskell
             QuasiQuotes
             OverloadedStrings
             CPP
             MultiParamTypeClasses
             TypeFamilies
             GADTs
             GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving
             FlexibleContexts
             EmptyDataDecls
             NoMonomorphismRestriction



  main-is:             source/Main.hs
  -- other-modules:       
  build-depends:       base          == 4.5.*
                     , http-types   
                     , template-haskell 
                     , wai           
                     , wai-extra     
                     , warp          
                     , yesod         == 1.1.9
```

This project builds and runs locally on my VM with similar stack, this includes shakespeare-js-1.0.2.

I tried the following:

- Forcing a newer or older version of shakespeare-js other than 1.0.2 in the .cabal file. The same compile error shows up.
- As a shot in the dark, I tried removing some extensions that might affect compilation such as TemplateHaskell from the .cabal file.

Edit:

- When I use shakespeare-js < 1.0.2 I get a compile error after heroku chooses 1.0.1 which also fails to compile.
- I can not get shakespeare-js-1.1.2 (the most recent version) to compile anywhere, not even locally.

I solved the error by forcing shakespeare < 1.0.3 
This does not solve the problem of not being able to compile the most recent versions of shakespeare (yesod).

Comment: Try with `shakespeare < 1.0.3`, not `shakespeare-js`.

Comment: Quick question: after the fix Daniel suggested, you don't get this error: `rejecting: ghc-paths-0.1.0.9 (unknown package: ghc)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the type `PreConvert` changed between [`shakespeare-1.0.2`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/shakespeare/1.0.2/doc/html/Text-Shakespeare.html#t%3aPreConvert) and [`shakespeare-1.0.3`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/shakespeare/1.0.3/doc/html/Text-Shakespeare.html#t%3aPreConvert).

In the older version, `preEscapeBegin` and `preEscapeEnd` were fields of the constructor `PreConvert`, but they have been removed in version 1.0.3.

So the solution is to

- use the older version of `shakespeare`, specify `shakespeare < 1.0.3` or
- use a new enough version of `shakespeare-js`, specify `shakespeare-js >= 1.1.2`.

(There may be further adjustments necessary if you use the newer `shakespeare` version, I haven't tried.)

Comment: Like he said, older and newer versions don't work either - I have the same problems for some days now.

Comment: I haven't tried, but I expect `shakespeare-js` to work _with the older version_ of `shakespeare`, and I more or less expect `shakespeare-js-1.1.2` to work with `shakespeare-1.0.3`. The latter may well also require newer versions of other packages, and perhaps the former requires using older versions of some other packages than cabal picks by default. But `shakespeare-1.0.3` certainly doesn't work with `shakespeare-js < 1.1.2`. What combinations have you tried?

Comment: Oh, I didn't read your comment carefully enough. I misread `shakespeare` in your first suggestion; in my last attempts, I tried different versions of `shakespeare-js`, older versions didn't work and newer versions brought new problems that I couldn't solve. However, the error mentioned above doesn't occur anymore with the restriction `shakespeare < 1.0.3`. So thanks for the tip!