# Error "unknown package: ghc" when building heroku app with yesod

Tags: haskell, heroku, yesod

I'm trying to build a heroku app with a new version of yesod (1.1.9), unfortunately it fails becauce of the `ghc-paths` dependency (yesod version 1.1.2 works since it does not have this dependency). I tried various dependencies and all possible `ghc-paths` versions, but in the end I always get this awkward error message that ghc is an unknown package. A local build works just fine with the same dependencies.

```
main-is:           main.hs
hs-source-dirs:    app
build-depends:   base          == 4.5.*
                 , http-types
                 , shakespeare == 1.0.2
                 , template-haskell 
                 , wai           
                 , wai-extra     
                 , warp          
                 , yesod         == 1.1.9
```

.

```
[176] rejecting: ghc-paths-0.1.0.9 (unknown package: ghc)
[__6] fail (backjumping, conflict set: TestHeroku, ghc, yesod)
[__5] rejecting: yesod-1.1.8.2, ... , 0.0.0.2, 0.0.0.1, 0.0.0 (conflict: TestHeroku => yesod==1.1.9)
[__0] fail (backjumping, conflict set: TestHeroku, ghc, yesod)
```

Shakespeare is needed because of the error mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15044336/shakespeare-js-fails-to-compile-on-heroku/) and I use the [heroku-buildpack-haskell](https://github.com/pufuwozu/heroku-buildpack-haskell).

Comment: Check if ghc is a visible package?

Comment: Just checked, it's not listed, but I also tried to specify ghc in the dependencies and it didn't to the trick. So, how do I make it visible then?

Comment: @ichistmeinname What OS are you using?

Comment: @ichistmeinname Can you try to expose the ghc package and then try. It might be hidden.

Comment: I'd speculate this is a Linux distribution which does not install the ghc package at all by default. If it's merely hidden, it should still be known to Cabal.

Comment: Just noticing, but... `ghc-paths` doesn't actually list `ghc` as a dependency. Nor do any of its modules import from there. So...???

Comment: @kosmikus The used OS is Ubuntu 10.04.

Comment: This is a little off-topic, but I've found AWS to be great for Haskell deploys (if you can't crack it on Heroku).

Comment: @ichistmeinname Hmm, 10.04 comes with ghc-6.12.1, right? So you installed a newer GHC yourself, by building from source? What does `ghc-pkg list ghc` say?

Comment: @kosmikus I didn't install anything new, because I'm working with the configuration of the haskell-buildpack that I mentioned in my post. The guys behind that project installed ghc-7.4.1: `ghc-pkg list ghc` gives `/app/tmp/repo.git/.cache/ghc/lib/ghc-7.4.1/package.conf.d:`

Comment: @ichistmeinname Sorry, I hadn't quite understood the remark about the buildpack. So it seems the buildpack does not include the `ghc` package, but you need it, as `yesod` now depends on it. If that package isn't included, you cannot easily install it yourself, so it'd seem to be as if the buildpack needs to be fixed.

Comment: @kosmikus Well, I started to suspect that kind of answer. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @kosmikus you should post your comments as an answer so they can be accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone struggles with the same problem, I took matters into my own hands and created a new buildpack based on the versions that are already circulating. It runs with yesod-1.1.9.

https://github.com/ichistmeinname/heroku-buildpack-haskell